# window.open opens a new tab instead of a new window (in chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

I have a code that used to open a popup window in all browsers, but now chrome started opening a new tab instead.

Does anyone knows what did they change and how do I open a popup window now?

This is my code:

```
function openWindow(url, title) {
  window.open(url, title, 'height=640,width=960,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,status=no');
}
```

Comment: try replacing the variable title with the string '_blank'

Comment: Tried it, same behaviour. Also, this exact code used to, and it still works, on other browsers...

Comment: This fiddle correctly opens a popup on both chrome and mozilla for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kelervin/Pf8Rw/ i am using Chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 m

Comment: is it possible that you need to change this setting? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?hl=en

Comment: It looked promising I must say, but it did not work. I'm pretty sure its only my browser, but I'm not sure why...

Comment: let's go with the basics (and unrelated) things then, have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Yes, done that... also restarted and tried it with other chrome users (but on the same computer)

Comment: I had the same issue while developing.  Closed "Developer Tools", tried again, and now it opens a new window as expected.  Go figure...

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this code please?

```
function openWindow(url, title) {
    var myWindow = window.open(url, title, "height=640,width=960,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,status=no");
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/C0dekid/go96uk5r/5/

Comment: this is the exact example that stopped working on chrome (the example too).

Comment: What is the version of the Google Chrome you are using?

Comment: 49.0.2623.87 - the latest

Comment: That's weird, I have tested it on the following browsers: Google Chrome (Latest), Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer, Microsoft Edge. They all open the popup instead of opening it in new tab.

Answer (score 2):

i think the problem is in the second argument. check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp). *name - The name of the window (Note: the name does not specify the title of the new window)*

Comment: can you add the argument you send to the function?

Comment: I'm doing something similar to this: <button onclick="openWindow('http://www.google.com', 'test123456')">Click</button>

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
window.open('https://www.google.com', 'MyWindow1', "height=640,width=960,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,status=no");
```

What is your Chrome version?

My version is 49.0.2623.87 m

Comment: I'm on 49.0.2623.87 (same as you), but my links open in a new tab. Maybe it's something in my browser's settings?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you tried with my code? What is your OS?

Comment: Yes, the exact same code. I'm running chrome on OSX (yosemite)

Comment: Ok I'm on Windows 7, maybe that's the point... An other thing that comes to my mind is that clicking with the third click (the mouse wheel click) always opens in a news tab. Perhaps it is related to a mouse config?

Comment: No, I don't even have a third button (stupid mac...). I see other machines that behave normally, I'm not sure what's different from mine.

Comment: The toolbar=yes parameter recently caused Chrome to open these in a new tab rather than window (for a coworker and I, my version is 59.0.3071.115). I removed toolbar=yes and it went back to opening a new window as intended.

Answer (score 0):

### Generally / ALSO...

This seems to happen whenever you pass an invalid comma delimited "**settings** string" as your 3rd (settings) param, i.e. `window.open(url, window_title, settings)`.

*So, check your spelling, look for errors, make sure you haven't specified (passed in) incorrect/incompatible options in that string.*

It seems when this happens the `window.open()` call will just ignore the whole **OPEN IN A NEW WINDOW concept**, and just opens the specified URL (as best it can retrieve it) in a new/next tab.